# Google Apps SAML SSO enabled but normal users still can login using google.com/a/domainame.com

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, saml

We have enabled SSO for our Google Apps Domain. When users try to access "http://mail.google.com/a/domainname.com" they get redirected to the custom SSO Sign in page url. But when url http://google.com/a/domainame.com is accessed users are able to login to google apps users hub without being redirected to SSO sign in page url. As per my understanding, this kind of login should be only enabled for administrator of domain. Why is it happening for normal users of our domain.

How can we redirect http://google.com/a/domainname.com" url to custom sso sign in page. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can they actually login ? I guess only admins can login at http://google.com/a/domainname.com. As long as a user does not explicitly type this URL, he will never see this login page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't block people from logging into Google through 'local' credentials, if they know them: they need this for access via mobile devices, where you can't be redirected to a web page for SAML SSO, for example.

The normal solution is to change the password to something the user doesn't know.

Further, if you force 2-factor authentication for your users, this means a user can have one-time passwords for their mobile devices and still have an account password they don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The www.google.com/a/yourdomain.com url points to google cpanel, which can never, ever be restricted through custom SSO, as this is your only recourse to disable SSO.  If anything goes wrong, you need to hit that url to turn off SSO or change SSO settings.

If you wish to restrict access to cpanel, please look into organizations restrictions / superuser privileges; you can restrict cpanel superadmins to only one or two trusted admins.

If you wish to have only a single admin account with access to cpanel, but want to give some cpanel features to regular users, check out some third party apps in the google marketplace; gPanel is especially good as it gives you fine grained control over who can access what.  Couple that with SSO, and you get a complete logging / monitoring / access control solution.